# Allow calling function to override default options - jQuery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, inversion-of-control

I want the callingFunction to be able to override the default options provided in the `showDivPopUp` function.

```
function calling(){
  showDivPopUp("title of pop up box", "message to show", 
        {
            buttons:{
                        Yes: function () {
                                $(this).dialog("destroy");
                            },
                        No :function () {
                                $(this).dialog("destroy");
                            }                        
                    }      
        });
}

function showDivPopUp(title,msg,options){
  var mgDiv = $("#msgDiv");
  mgDiv.attr("innerHTML", msg);
  return mgDiv.dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Ok: function () {
        $(this).dialog("destroy");
      }
    },
    resizable: true,
    show: "explode",
    position: "center",
    closeOnEscape: true,
    draggable: false,
    title : titl,
    open: function (event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
  });
}
```

So, the above code should show two buttons viz. `Yes` and `No` instead of just  `OK`. I don't want to do `if` check for each option.

**UPDATE:**
In options parameter there might be options for which default is not applied. So the calling function may specify `size` option which is not mentioned in the `showDivPopUp` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use the JQuery extend() method to merge the options you pass into the function with the defaults that are specified within it.

See:
http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/05/14/javascript-default-options-pattern.html
and
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

```
//calling function source excluded, use exactly the same.

function showDivPopUp(title, msg, options) {

    //create basic default options
    var defaults = {
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $(this).dialog("destroy");
            }
        },
        resizable: true,
        show: "explode",
        position: "center",
        closeOnEscape: true,
        draggable: false,
        title: title,
        open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
    }

    //merge the specified options with the defaults.
    //in example case, will have the above except with the new buttons specified
    if (typeof options == 'object') {
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);
    } else {
        options = defaults;
    }


    var mgDiv = $("#msgDiv");
    mgDiv.attr("innerHTML", msg);
    return mgDiv.dialog(options); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like 'options' is in JSON format.  Try omitting the first `{buttons:` portion in the 3rd argument to showDivPopUp or set `buttons: options.buttons` in the showDivPopUp function.

To expand on this, create more json pairs, and test for their existence in the showDivPopUp function.  Exists?  Override.  Doesn't exist?  Keep defaults.

```
{buttons:{
  Yes: function () {
    $(this).dialog("destroy");
  },
  No :function () {
    $(this).dialog("destroy");
  }                        
},
background:"blue",
fontsize:15
}
```

Access each via:

```
options.buttons
options.background
options.fontsize
```

Test for existence using:

```
if ( typeof( window[ 'option.fontsize' ] ) != "undefined" ) {override code}
```

Response to the update in the question:
Use [jquery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each) to iterate over all elements in the passed option.

Comment: Please see the update in question. Sorry for not mentioning it earlier

Comment: I don't want to do if check for each option otherwise think what about any new option specified by calling function

Comment: I think there lies the answer in `Use jquery.each to iterate over all elements in the passed option`. I will try it after lunch. I might do a `foreach` instead. Lets see. Thanks very much.

Comment: foreach is faster by more than 2x.  However, $.each() creates separate function scopes for each iteration.  See http://www.bennadel.com/blog/534-The-Beauty-Of-The-jQuery-Each-Method.htm for details.  Both will work just fine, but I opt to use jquery by default because cross-browser quirks happen so much less when you do.  =)

Comment: It's breaking what you want to write. You can enclose the code within  backticks (`). Refer http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Can you please explain what you want to say after "..happens so much less when you do..."

Comment: I was just saying using jquery instead of standard javascript tends to cause weird bugs and browser quirks to show up much less frequently.  After that phrase, I just have a smiley face.

Answer (score 0):

In your `mgDiv.dialog` function, modify the `buttons` key to have a conditional value. E.g.:

```
function showDivPopUp(title,msg,options){
  var mgDiv = $("#msgDiv");
  mgDiv.attr("innerHTML", msg);
  return mgDiv.dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: options.buttons || {
      Ok: function () {
        $(this).dialog("destroy");
      }
    },
    resizable: true,
    show: "explode",
    position: "center",
    closeOnEscape: true,
    draggable: false,
    title : titl,
    open: function (event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. It's just not about buttons, other options might be overridden by the calling function. So is there anyway other way than doing it for each options. Also in options parameter there might be options for which default is not applied. See the updates for clarification.

Comment: One of the benefits of using configuration objects is that parameters become optional and you only need specify what you want. Because of this you will need to perform tests. The easiest way is with `||` (logical or).

Comment: Agreed! But I hope you understand this statement `calling function may specify size option which is not mentioned in the showDivPopUp function.`