# jQueryUI modal add function to defaults

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I always find myself fixing [this chrome scrollbar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617638/scrollbar-problem-with-jquery-ui-dialog-in-chrome-and-safari) on every jQueryUI modal I add. So, I was thinking that I could add that code to the jqueryUI dialog defaults. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756193/allow-calling-function-to-override-default-options-jquery-ui-dialog) but can't quite bridge the gap and apply it to my code.

```
$.extend($.ui.dialog.prototype.options, {
    open: function(event, ui){
        window.setTimeout(function(){jQuery(document).unbind('mousedown.dialog-overlay').unbind('mouseup.dialog-overlay');}, 100);
    }
});
```

The problem is, if I have code in a dialog open event, it will override the default.

```
$("#modalContent").dialog({
    open:function(){
        alert('Hey buddy!');
    }
});
```

So my question is two parts; How do I stack the functions instead of overriding them and should I even do this in the first place? Thanks!

Here is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/McWatt/HSA8M/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is alot simpler then that. You can just remove those events by overriding `$.ui.dialog.overlay.events`, which will prevent them from being bound to begin with:

```
$.ui.dialog.overlay.events = $.map('focus,keydown,keypress'.split(','),
        function(event) { return event + '.dialog-overlay'; }).join(' ');
```

*Note: If you remove keydown you won't be able to close the dialog with the escape key. You might want to look at overriding the `create`-method as well. Check the [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.8.16/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js) for more info.*

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/cvCYd/show/)

Comment: Marcus, your fix works great..I don't see the issue with the escape button though. The dialog still closes - which is what I want actually. Maybe it's my version of chrome (stable 14). The only problem I have is I'm not quite sure how your fix overriding those events. I'll have to study it later. :) Now to decide to implement or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have one problem in your jsfiddle:

- the dialog is not destroyed and therefore the open callback remains the same

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/HSA8M/3/

Still, I would not really recommend modifying the defaults of a library object. In my opinion it is a lot safer to create your own ui.widget based on ui.dialog and override the defaults in your object.

Your case seems to be rather simple but where should we draw the line between clean and entangled code?

Comment: You are wrong about [`jQuery.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/). It does return the extended object, but if you pass a varible it will be extended and you don't need to replace the original.

Comment: sure there are ways to fix it without overriding the defaults, but then again modal dialogs shouldn't really be bigger then the window itself ;)

Comment: @topek destroying the modal causes any edits to the form within to be destroyed along with it. The requirements I have are to keep the edits. I agree with not mucking up the library object, but maybe in this case it is okay to save on a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: oops, destroy doesn't seem to wipe out modal form edits...nevermind :)